# Eclipse PHP autocomplete acting funny, some files complete some don't

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

The orgional problem was that for some files the autocomplete would not complete things like "self" and "public" and if I would type self:: it would not show a list of functions.

The other problem was that for some files it would complete but not show functions of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase when the class extends that so typing $th would complete to: "$this->" but the resulting list would not show assertEquals (which is a function of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase).

Solved the first problem by changing:

```
throw(new Exception("Something wrong with the datastore",666));
```

to

```
throw new Exception("Something wrong with the datastore",666);
```

(taken the throw parameter out of it's parentheses)

To add autocomplete for 3rd party libraries like phpunit do the following:

```
under project=>properties
  =>php include path (list on the left)
  =>libraries tab
  =>add external source folder
  =>added /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/
```

Comment: what version of Eclipse?

Comment: Version: 4.2.1
Build id: M20120914-1800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eclipse to hint base class methods, the file containing that class must either be a part of current project, or linked to it. Navigate to Project -> Properties -> PHP Include Path; you can permanently add an external library / source folder to your project there.

As for Eclipse not hinting `self` and `$this`, are you sure you're typing inside of a class method? Obviously, these words have no use anywhere else.

Comment: You are on to something here, it's showing procedural functions only for the problematic file but there is no syntax error and I am typing in the right place. For example adding a public function; when typing pu it doesn't complete to public and $ completes to things like $_COOKIE

Comment: @HMR All right, but are you typing `pu` inside of a pair of class-defining brackets? Like: `class Foo { pu... }`? Also in Project -> Properties -> PHP Interpreter make sure you don't have "Project specifing settings" set to PHP4.

Comment: Hi lafor, thank you for looking into my problem; yes, I did type at the right place. I've updated the original question because I found out what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.buildpath` if all the folders with base classes and the classes you want to have autocomplete in are included there.

If you're including external libraries you can add them to the include path of your project.

Comment: The problem is that for some files autocomplete doesn't list simple things like $this and never shows methods of the class itself and for some files it does.