# eclipse autocomplete fails in PHP when using parentheses

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm using eclipse Juno with PDT. Autocomplete works fine except in a specific situation.
If I do this it works fine

```
class Example {
    public function doit() {
         $v = new Example();
    }
}
```

I can control-click the Example() object fine and also I see the doit() method when autocompleting $v->.

Now see this example

```
class Example2 {
    public function doit() {
        $v = (new Example2());
    }
}
```

Now the autocompleter is broken, I cannot control-click anything but also the outline view is now empty. Eclipse cannot see any methods or anything. There is nothing in the eclipse logs.

Of course this is a stupid example but I've seen this construction happening in statements with the ternary operator in external frameworks. This is pretty annoying because the objects from such classes cannot be used anymore with the autocompleter.

This call relates to [Eclipse PHP autocomplete acting funny, some files complete some don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13529057/801072) btw where I also replied with the actual issue. Please don't shoot me for re-posting.

Comment: The problem can be reproduced on PDT 3.2.0/Kepler and it seems to be a bug of PDT.  
"$v = (new Example2());" causes incorrect parsing. See Outline view. There is no classes, but when you commented out that statement, class Example2 will appear.  
If you put the script into php 5.3 project(project properties->php interpreter->enable project specific settings->php 5.3), there is no problem. Probably PDT parser for php 5.4 is broken.  
I believe there is no workaround.(unless removing parenthesis)

Comment: This is a great find because I'm using PHP 5.3 which solves my problem. Post it as an answer and I will give you points :)